# htaccess to add directory after domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, directory

How can I use htaccess to always ADD a directory immediately after the domain name?

So for example, change requests for
`http://domain.com/path-to/file.php`
to
`http://domain.com/added-directory/path-to/file.php`

The context here is that i am migrating a site to a new server, and the domain name is not yet pointed to the new server. But the hosting company provides me with a "temporary url" based on the Shared IP and my account username, so `http://216.172.172.211/~myusername/` , but all the paths in all the html are doc-root relative, like /images/logo.png, which translates to `http://216.172.172.211/images/logo.png` which is wrong. I need it to be `http://216.172.172.211/~myusername/images/logo.png` .

Answer (score 0):

try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~myusername
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~myusername/$1 [L]
```

If you want to redirect so that URLs show the `~myusername` part in the URL address bar, add an `R` flag to the square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~myusername/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to do it. I did change `~myusername` to my actual username. I tried with and without the R=301. No luck either way.

Comment: @tzeldin88 Are you sure your htaccess file is being read (needs `AllowOverride All` in server/vhost config)? Are you sure mod_rewrite is loaded? Are there other rules that are being applied before this one is reached?

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. I was able to get a dedicated IP for the site, which solved my bigger issue of viewing the site from the server document-root. So I didn't need to continue troubleshooting the htaccess issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me perfectly

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/~gye 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/gye/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. If an URL comes without the /XYZ
2. Add https:// at the beginning and /gye/ after the domain.

Testing here really helped: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/